# How can an account be temporarily suspended until the year 1992?

Tags: discussion, suspensions

When looking at the details of an account  I noticed that it was temporarily suspended:

[image]

The suspension ends in 1992, or 2092, or generally speaking in *92. None of the years make sense.

What does that message mean?

Comment: The user is suspended until 18 March 2292.

Comment: Can the reopen voters explain why they think this question is any different to the linked thread?